# Why do only humans commit suicide?

Tags: death

Why is it that only humans commit suicide?

Many animals do 'brave' things to protect their children or family, and some male spiders sacrifice themselves so that they can impregnate the females. However, humans commit suicide without necessarily any intention to help their offspring. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I think the answer is along the lines of `Because advanced cognitive abilities`

Comment: I'm pretty sure some dolphins are smarter than some people who have committed suicide :)

Comment: Probably not, although it depends on what one mean by "intelligence". Be careful, I guess some people may feel insulted by what you just said as it almost suggest that one need to be stupid to commit suicide.

Comment: I do hope nobody inferred that, I meant nothing of the sort. I do, however, think that 'advanced cognitive abilities' isn't a good explanation in itself. If those abilities make the idea of suicide conceivable, then why is that?

Comment: @NeMo Spiders and other primitive animals probably work a lot like robots, taking in input and doing output, and never actually think about what they're doing. The human brain is powerful enough to realize how crappy life can feel and rationalize that suicide is an acceptable solution. We also have the planning ability, knowledge, and technology to follow through with it.

Comment: @NeMo Spiders do not know existential crisis :P

Comment: First, I think we have to question the idea that only humans commit suicide.  How do you define 'suicide'?  Is the squirrel running out in front of your car committing suicide?

Comment: Bees commit suicide

Comment: I don't know. Did the squirrel look sad?

Comment: Untreated depression is the most common cause of suicide attempts. Many animals are capable of experiencing depression so this is a very complicated question to answer, however there is [no documented case](http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pr0.101.3.831-848) of suicide in non-humans. Perhaps cross post to Cognitive.SE and see if they can help out.

Comment: @jamesqf I should have tagged you in the above post. This, oddly enough, has been defined in the academic community. The citation explains that although sparse examples exist of deliberate self endangerment, the researchers failed to find an example of non-human species *deliberately* killing themselves.

Comment: This is more of a cognition question than biology IMO.

Comment: ["7 Cases of Animals that Committed Suicide"](http://www.oddee.com/item_98725.aspx) and other stories in ["Why do only humans commit suicide?"](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110607212034AAUOCHE), think upon those which are not mere sacrifices. :)

Answer (score -2):

Animals can hurt themselves to save their life for example foxes and tigers falling in traps are known to chew their paws to escape from the trap. Thus one can argue that all living creatures want to live and to escape death as well as losing freedom.

looking at how animals live, an animal can always use its capabilities to escape danger or problems as well as to look for food for survival. In humans who commit suicide sometimes it is because  there is no "exit". for example some people commit suicide due to being unable to pay their loans it is the feeling of distress losing all hope and the fact that it is hard to escape from problems in a human society that lead to this thinking.

so a person doing so is trying to escape the problems instead of facing them. further, the fact that humans have the concept of "responsibility" and being held accountable by members of the society all these lead to this thinking as the only escape

Comment: You really ought to back up your answer with sources

Comment: I haven't heard of limb gnawing before. It [appears it is at least controversial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AAnimal_trapping#Animal_gnaws_its_own_leg_off_to_escape_trap_--_myth_or_not.3F) as to whether this has happened, although I haven't looked at either side in any detail.